# Why does presentViewController affect my navigation button icon size?

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller

This has been an issue because I do not understand the logic of what happens when the presentViewController is presenting an alertController. Please help me extend my understanding. This is how I am calling the alterViewController.

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) { }
```

Before the alterController is called the navigation icons looks as below:

[image]

After the alterController is been loaded and waiting for action("OK" to be tapped) this is what happens:

[image]

Please assist. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to change UIModalPresentationStyle of `alertController` to `.FullScreen` ?

Comment: Yep. I have. Still same results.